# How to make intellij show "this file is indented with tabs instead of 4 spaces" again

Tags: intellij-idea

As we know in Intellij idea, it will show "This file is indented with tabs instead of 4 spaces" and 3 selections "OK    Indent with 4 spaces   Show Settings" when I opened a new file.

But, unfortunately I selected "Indent with 4 spaces" by mistake.

How can I select the "OK" instead? Or in other way, show the selections again?

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

> **To toggle between tabs and spaces**
>
> - On the main menu, choose Edit | Convert Indents , and then choose To
>     Spaces or To Tabs respectively

**Source:** https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/changing-indentation.html